# How to make variable text as Xpath expression

Tags: xslt-2.0

Please suggest to get Xpath expression from the variable text. As xpath expression is stored in a variable as a text. From earlier suggestions were suggesting **evaluate** function, but unable to get.

**XML:**

```
<article>
<float>
    <fig id="fig1">Figure 1</fig>
    <fig id="fig2" type="color">Figure 2</fig>
    <fig id="fig3" type="color">Figure 3</fig>
    <fig id="fig4" type="color">Figure 4</fig>
</float>
```

**XSLT 2.0:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:param name="varColorFig"><xsl:text>//float/fig[@type='color']</xsl:text></xsl:param><!-- Xpath stored in variable as a text-->
<!--xsl:variable name="names" as="element(name)*"><xsl:evaluate xpath="$varColorFig" context-item="."/></xsl:variable-->

<xsl:template match="article">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <xsl:element name="ColorFigCount">
            <xsl:if test="count(//float/fig[@type='color']) gt 0">
                <a><xsl:value-of select="count(//float/fig[@type='color'])"/></a>
            </xsl:if><!--real Xpath expression format-->
            
            <xsl:if test="count($varColorFig) gt 0">
                <b><xsl:value-of select="count($varColorFig)"/></b>
            </xsl:if><!-- xpath stored in variable as text, then needs to get as Xpath here, but it is not processing as Xpath.-->
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Required Result:** `<b>3</b>` is the required, but now getting 1.

```
<article>
<float>
    <fig id="fig1">Figure 1</fig>
    <fig id="fig2" type="color">Figure 2</fig>
    <fig id="fig3" type="color">Figure 3</fig>
    <fig id="fig4" type="color">Figure 4</fig>
</float>
<ColorFigCount><a>3</a><b>3</b></ColorFigCount>
</article>
```

Comment: `xsl:evaluate` seems the right tool if you can use an XSLT 3 processor that supports it (I think Saxon 10 in all editions or Saxon 9.8 or 9.9 with PE or EE, Saxon JS 2, Altova XML 2017 R3 and later). Which XSLT processor do you use? Can you use Saxon 10 HE or Saxon JS 2

Answer (score 1):

In XSLT 3 with `xsl:evaluate` support your code would look as follows (assumes `expand-text="yes"` is enabled):

```
  <xsl:param name="varColorFig"><xsl:text>//float/fig[@type='color']</xsl:text></xsl:param><!-- Xpath stored in variable as a text-->
  <xsl:variable name="names" as="element(fig)*"><xsl:evaluate xpath="$varColorFig" context-item="."/></xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="article">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
          <colorFigCount>{count($names)}</colorFigCount>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

The `xsl:param` could be shortened to `<xsl:param name="varColorFig">//float/fig[@type='color']</xsl:param>`, I don't see a need for `xsl:text`.

Comment: Sir, Thanks for the suggesting in XSLT3, is there any chance to get help in XSLT2. Plus one sir.

Comment: @RudramuniTP, I am afraid dynamic XPath evaluation as a language feature was introduced in XSLT 3, in XSLT 2 you will need to look into extensions provided by some versions of a particular XSLT 2 processor, for instance, Saxon PE and EE in earlier 9.x versions have https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation9.7/functions/saxon/evaluate.html

Comment: If there is no extension function in your environment, then all you can do for the generic case is to first generate an XSLT stylesheet with the expression passed in as a parameter, then run the generated stylesheet. You will need to use `xsl:namespace-alias` in the first step and some host language to run the two transformations.